# Can't create table with jpa+spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to generate table using JPA. but i can't create it. There is no error in the code, but it seems that there is configuration error. but i can't find it, i tried many configurations but nothing happen. 
Thanks a lot.

This is `application.property`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springapp
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= me
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

this is my class:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public Customer(String name, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public Customer() {
        super();
    }
}
```

This is the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And this is the controller:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

```
@RequestMapping("/findall")
@ResponseBody
public List<Customer> findAll() {
    return customerRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GStock-3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>GStock-3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: it seems right ..what error you get? is table created in mysql?

Comment: when i check the database, i can't find the table castomer

Comment: go through it:https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: hi do you have sample code github

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `@EntityScan`

```
@EntityScan("<package with entities>")
@SpringBootApplication 
public class Application { ... }
```

Comment: where in customer.java?

Comment: No. Near 
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application

Comment: Yesss it works finally, I added @EntityScan("<package with entities>") in application.java. Thank you nikolay and all the others for you help.

Comment: Thanks @NikolaiShevchenko but with or witout ```@EntityScan```, I get error **"com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=MY_USER;CREATE TABLE;DSNDB04, DRIVER=4.29.24"**  I use Spring Data JPA and by data source is DB2 database.  Any idea why I am getting this error?  It seem that user MY_USER does not have priviledge to issue CREATE TABLE command; however, I dont know what are priviledges required by Hibernate / JPA.

Comment: @pixel user on whose behalf SQL commands are run might require some set of privileges, but JPA (including Hibernate engine) itself doesn't require any privilieges.

Comment: Thanks @NikolaiShevchenko.  I figured out what the problem was.  For DB2, I need to provide schema to my entity's @Table annotation like ```@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "CAR_VIEW", schema = "MY_SCHEMA") 
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
   ...```.  With that, the problem with DB2 is gone but now my H2 stopped working so need to figure out how to use entity with schema with H2 database?

Answer (score 1):

With the current information I have a couple of suggestions / Questions that might help you allong:

- Does the "springapp" database exist with the correct user (root) and password (me) assigned to it in MySQL
- Has MySQL been started?
- I see no @Repository definition in your code e.g.

  @Repository
  public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository{}

Comment: yes i have interface extends jpaRepository. the springapp exists with the same username and password. i did: use springapp; show tables:empty set

Comment: The same thing, it's really wreid, !

Comment: Note: I was working with normal spring, with the same username and password, and i used jpa anad i generated tables normally. But now, i moved to spring boot it don't work, i think it's configuration  problem.

Answer (score 0):

execute following on your mysql:

> mysql> create database db_example; -- Create the new database
>
> mysql> create user 'springuser'@'localhost' identified by 'ThePassword'; -- Creates the user
>
> mysql> grant all on db_example.* to 'springuser'@'localhost'; -- Gives all the privileges to the new user on the newly created database

and add into `application.xml`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

OR

you can go through [this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)